# How to handle HTML forms with PHP?

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to create a simple contact form that takes user-inputted data and e-mails it to me. however, when I use the following code and the user presses submit, the page is redirected to a blank page (/form.php) - not even the "Thank you!" shows up on it, nor is the e-mail even sent. Can someone point out any errors I'm making? thanks!

PHP:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $myEmail = "myemail@gmail.com";
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = "Message from $email";
    $message = "

    Name: $name
    E-mail: $email

    Message:
    $message

    ";

    /* Sends to e-mail. */
    mail($myEmail, $subject, $message, "hello");

?>

Thank you!

<?php
}
?>
```

HTML:

```
<form id="form" method="post" name="contact-form" action="form.php">
    Name: <br>
    <input type="text" name="name" /><br><br>

    Email:<br>
    <input type="text" name="email" /><br><br>

    Message:<br>
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Tell me anything!"></textarea><br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Comment: You're declaring `$message` with your message then you're including `$message` inside it. Seems like it's stuck in an endless loop and is fighting to get out.

Comment: Try putting `herpaderp` before the first `<?php` in the `form.php` file. If that doesn't appear, then you have a syntax error and `display_errors` is disabled.

Comment: I'm just curious why do you need to get the second curly brace in a separate PHP tag? :)

Comment: @RoverMAX I'm not entirely sure to be honest, I saw it done in other people's code. But I think it's so the function can display the HTML text before the PHP is done executing.

Comment: What HTML text? @user3451233

Comment: @Fred-ii- The "Thank you!" right after the first closing PHP tag.

Comment: I'll edit my answer. @user3451233

Comment: @jpdstan Reload my answer, I added an extra header `$headers = "From: $email" . "\r\n";` that way you will see the Email address as the `From` otherwise Email risks in landing in Spam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're declaring `$message` with your message (as part of the [`mail() header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)) then you're including `$message` inside it, in turn hashing and bashing your header.

Try this method instead.

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $myEmail = "myemail@gmail.com";
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = "Message from $email";
    $message2 = "

    Name: $name
    E-mail: $email

    Message: 
    $message

    ";

    /* Sends to e-mail. */
    if(mail($myEmail, $subject, $message2, "hello")){

    echo "<b>Thank you</b>"; // HTML bold text.
    }

    else{
    echo "<h2>Sorry, there was an error.</h2>";
    }
}
?>
```

If you want to send email as HTML you need to use the following:

```
$headers = "From: $email" . "\r\n";
$headers  .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

then change what is above:

```
if(mail($myEmail, $subject, $message2, "hello"))
```

to read as:

```
if(mail($myEmail, $subject, $message2, $headers))
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed 2 problems.

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $myEmail = "myemail@gmail.com";
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = "Message from $email";
    $message = "

    Name: ".$name."
    E-mail: ".$email."

    Message:
    ".$_POST['message']."

    ";

    /* Sends to e-mail. */
    mail($myEmail, $subject, $message);

?>

Thank you!

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: why do you use the dots and quotations in front and behind the variables when declaring message? Sorry I'm new to PHP!

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out: for anyone wondering, it's just the syntax for PHP's string concatenation.